# How to set value into input field where placeholder contains "email"

Tags: placeholder, nightwatch.js, setvalue

Ques: **How to set value into input field where placeholder contains "email" using nightwatch.js ?** Please explain

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
browser.setValue('input[placeholder="email"]', 'someValue');
```

The [api reference](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#setValue) can be somewhat helpful to figure out stuff like this on your own.

Answer (score 1):

`browser.clearValue('input[placeholder="email"]');
browser.setValue('*Updated css locator of email field*', 'someValue');`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

There is another one way to set value in `input` by using JS jQuery:

- Chrome DevTools Console: `var email = jQuery("#email");
  email.val('test');`
- NightwatchJS: `browser.execute("jQuery('#email").val('test')");`

or

- `browser.execute("document.querySelector('#email').setRangeText('test')")`